# Handling Google API OAuth2 Redirect URL with ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to authorize the Google Contacts API using OAuth2. However, their instructions for .NET are only for MVC ([site documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc)) and no solution for ASP.NET WebForms.  I found code online that looks like

```
 Dim credential = CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets With {.ClientId = ClientID, .ClientSecret = clientSecret},
                                                        scopes,
                                                        Me.User.Identity.Name,
                                                        CancellationToken.None,
                                                        New OAuthDataStore()).Result
```

However, I get a 404 not found after the redirect because the /authorize URL doesn't exists.

Do I have to create this manually, or is that something that the `CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest` should be doing?  If that's what `CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest` should be handling for me, what do I need to do in WebForms to handle that.

In MVC I see they have all you need is a `AppFlowMetadata` in a `AuthCallbackController`.  Is there an equivalent for WebForms?

Comment: main problem you will have is that contacts is a Gdata API which means you are going to have to use the Gdata library as well as the current client library.   Or we have to figure out how to work Oauth2 with the gdata library

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the redirectUri issue?